# I don't know to find counterexample of continuous map

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous map from $X$ onto $Y$. If $X$ satisfies one of the countability axioms, or is separable, or is normal, does the same necessarily holds for $Y$?

I don't know counterexamples of these questions. Please help me...

Comment: Consider $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ where the first $\mathbb{R}$ is standard and the second has the discrete topology.

Comment: Or the second has the trivial topology

Comment: @Cbjork Thank you for your help. I know that is why counterexample! Thank you

Comment: @Peter Thank you for your help... I was very surprised that why I could not solve this problem!

Comment: @Cbjork.  The first function is invalid as it is not continuous.  The second is not a counter example.

Comment: @Johndo.  Cbjork's answers are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ has the discrete topology, any function $f: X \to Y$ is continuous.

Any discrete space is first countable and normal, perfectly normal etc. So if we take $Y$ any space that is **not** first countable , or normal, etc. and we take $X=Y$ as sets, $f=\textrm{id}$ and we give $X$ the discrete topology, we already have a counterexample for the respective property.

This idea works also for second countable: if we have a countable space $Y$ (because then $Y$ in the discrete topology is also second countable). There are plenty of non-second countable but countable spaces $Y$.

The image of a separable space under a continuous map *is* separable, so no example there.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will take a little more time to think about it.